# How to perform foreach on object with is list of enum dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, foreach, enums

I have an enum like

```
  {
      e1 = 0, 
      e2 = 1,
      e3 = 2,
  }
```

and other enum like:

```
 enum MyOtherEnum
    {
        oe1 = 0, 
        oe2 = 1,
        oe3 = 2,
    }
```

and a few other enums. I deserialize json to object, and one of object member is  list of `MyEnum` or a list of `MyOtherEnum`.

I need to perform foreach on the list regardless type of enum

I checked if this member is a list and try to perform `foreach` on this list like this:

```
var itemValue = item.GetValue(json);
    
if (IsList(itemValue))
{
   foreach (var listItem in (IEnumerable<dynamic>)itemValue)
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```

What I have tried:

1. Cast to list of: dynamic, object, string or int did not work. It always required to cast to `IList<MyEnum>`
2. Get type of element from list by using

   ```
   Type type = itemValue.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
   ```

   but compiler displays an error

   > type is var but is used like Type

I know that some workaround is using string instead of enum, but I want to avoid it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Json.NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/), you could do this:

```
// here the itemValue is a dynamic
var itemValue = item.GetValue(json);
var token = JToken.Parse(itemValue.ToString());

if (token is JArray)
{
    IEnumerable<MyEnum> myEnums = token.ToObject<List<MyEnum>>();
    
    foreach (var listItem in myEnums)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

EDIT:
If you have another enum, I suggest you to change your JSON to be something like this:

**test.json:**

```
{
    "MyEnum":[ "2", "1", "2" ],
    "MyOtherEnum":[ "2", "1", "1" ],
}
```

So, you can do something like this:

```
string jsonData = string.Empty;
jsonData = File.ReadAllText(@"\test.json");

dynamic myEnums = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);

var myEnumValues = myEnums.MyEnum;
var otherEnumValues = myEnums.MyOtherEnum;

foreach (var listItem in myEnumValues)
{
    // do something
}

foreach (var listItem in otherEnumValues)
{
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Yes, but i need to perform foreach on list of different enum types independently, like in post: MyEnum or Other Enum.
But thank You for your time and kindness

Comment: Okay, I didn't understand about the other enum at first. I'm suggesting that you change the JSON structure, so code can understand which one is which.
I've edited my answer.